# Is there any method make multiple dataframe from xml file by using element tree?

Tags: python, xml, list, elementtree

```
<root>  
 <person age="18">  
    <name>hzj</name>  
    <sex>man</sex>  
 </person>  
 <person age="19" des="hello">  
    <name>kiki</name>  
    <sex>female</sex>  
 </person>  
</root>
list=[]
for node in xroot.findall('./root/person'):
    name = node.attrib.get('name')
    sex = node.find('sex').text
    df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['person','name','sex']
list.append(df)
```

I want person age 18 related data as one dataframe. age 19 is another dataframe. Then put these 2 data frame in one list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. assume your xml file is file.xml.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et 

xtree = et.parse("file.xml")
xroot = xtree.getroot()
dfar = {}
for node in xroot:
    age = node.attrib.get("age")
    dfar[f"{age}_df"]=pd.DataFrame()

for node in xroot:

    o_age = node.attrib.get("age")
    o_name = node.find("name").text
    o_sex = node.find("sex").text
    row = {"name":o_name,"sex":o_sex}
    df = dfar.get(f"{o_age}_df")
    dfar[f"{o_age}_df"] = df.append([row],ignore_index=True)


flist = list(dfar.items())
for i in flist:
    age = i[0]  
    df_of_age = i[1]
    df_of_age.to_csv(f"{age}.csv")
```

Comment: many thanks, it good. But it has some problem when i have many of age, is it has any other method like using loop to automate create dataframe?

Comment: @Jovisch i have updated the answer,not sure is this the best method..but should work

Comment: It work, one last question is how do i convert first dataframe(age18) into csv. I had tried use .to_csv but it didnt work. Because of flist is tuple.

Comment: @Jovisch if you want to save dataframe to csv,iterate over the flist array and save each dataframe to csv.. example `flist[0].to_csv()`

Comment: but it hs error:  flist[0].to_csv(r'c:/')
TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Could u give me a hint how do parse multiple xml files like this structure?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811237/i-trouble-in-how-do-parse-multiple-xml-file-and-process-it-as-dataframe-in-pytho

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<root>  
 <person age="18">  
    <name>hzj</name>  
    <sex>man</sex>  
 </person>  
 <person age="19" des="hello">  
    <name>kiki</name>  
    <sex>female</sex>  
 </person>  
 <person age="19" des="hi">  
    <name>jane</name>  
    <sex>female</sex>  
 </person>   
</root>'''

data_frames = {}

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for person in root.findall('.//person'):
  age = person.attrib['age']
  df = data_frames.get(age,None)
  if df is None:
    data_frames[age] = pd.DataFrame()
  data_frames[age]= data_frames[age].append({'name':person.find('./name').text,'sex':person.find('./sex').text},ignore_index=True)

for age,df in data_frames.items():
  print('{} --> {}'.format(age,df.head()))
```

output

```
18 -->   name  sex
0  hzj  man
19 -->    name     sex
0  kiki  female
1  jane  female
```

Comment: it worked, one last question is how i call 18 dataframe? may i use df[i] or?

Comment: Start by copy and paste of my code. If it works ( I think it is ), check what is wrong with your code. Let me know.

Comment: data_frames['19']   . It is not a list. It is a dict