# I trouble in how do parse multiple xml file and process it as dataframe in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want parse multi xml file into dataframe. There are same xpath.

I have used element tree and os Python library.It can parse all the files, but it print out empty dataframe. However if code without multiple file, it can work properly.

```
mypath = r'C:\Users\testFile'
files = [path.join(mypath, f) for f in listdir(mypath) if f.endswith('.xml')]

for file in files:
    xtree = et.parse(file)
    xroot = xtree.getroot()
    df_cols=['value']
    out_xml=pd.DataFrame(columns=df_cols)
    for node in xroot.findall(r'./Group[1]/Details/Section[3]/Subreport/Group/Group[1]/Details/Section/Field'):
        name = node.attrib.get('Name')
        value = node.find('Value').text
        out_xml = out_xml.append(pd.Series([value],index=df_cols),ignore_index=True)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(out_xml.values, (-1, 4)))
```

Comment: you want a final dataframe with all data?

Comment: Thanks for response.yup, i want all the dataframe. But it print out empty dataframe.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a single dataframe with all data,you need to concat each dataframe to one main dataframe

```
mypath = r'C:\testFile'
files = [path.join(mypath, f) for f in listdir(mypath) if f.endswith('.xml')]

mainDF = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    xtree = et.parse(file)
    xroot = xtree.getroot()
    df_cols=['value']
    out_xml=pd.DataFrame(columns=df_cols)
    for node in xroot.findall(r'./Group[1]/Details/Section[3]/Subreport/Group/Group[1]/Details/Section/Field'):
        name = node.attrib.get('Name')
        value = node.find('Value').text
        out_xml = out_xml.append(pd.Series([value],index=df_cols),ignore_index=True)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(out_xml.values, (-1, 4)))
    mainDF = pd.concat([mainDF,df])
 mainDF.to_csv("filename.csv")
```

Comment: but it nothing after i     mainDF.to_csv(r'C:\test\1.csv',index=None,
                            header=['fre','status','a','b']) or print(mainDF)

Comment: check whether your `df` dataframe has properly implemented..check if it is a dataframe and exist expected values..and save mainDF to csv after the for loop.cant reproduce the problem without the data.

Comment: Thanks, but it only output one file data. the other file output is gone.

Comment: @Jovisch i have updated answer,is this how you saved your file?

Comment: yup, i have use this (mainDF.to_csv )also,but didnt work. I only can get the one file's value now. but problem is cannot reshape array of size 570846 into shape (4)

Comment: saving should be after for loop.make sure the indentation.. if saving is in right position,then it should be issue with your loop of creating dataframes..debug few iterations and check whether your `df` dataframe is getting different dataframe in each round.